# Best way to create large array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I'm new to python and am trying to make a large array. Looking for the best method to do this.

Basically I am trying to make a large array in python to put into another application. The array will have a variable number of rows and 5 columns. I have data for two of the columns stored in other lists and would like to iterate through those lists to populate those two columns in my array.

It will look like:

```
x  y  z  l1 w1
x  y  z  l2 w2
x  y  z  l3 w3
x  y  z  l4 w4
x  y  z  l5 w5
x  y  z  l6 w6
x  y  z  l7 w7
```

I've seen posts about using lists, or arrays in numpy but nothing about looping through a list to populate them. Any suggestions?

Comment: `x  y  z  l1 w1` doesn't make this clear at all. So you want 5 columns but you're only giving 2 values, and the rest are names of things that don't exist.

Comment: @roganjosh the values in the first column will all be the same, the values in the second column will all be the same, the values in the third column will all be the same. The values in the fourth and fifth columns will be pulled in from two separate lists

Comment: Are the other two lists a python list object or are they already in a numpy array?  And will they be the same length or will they have the potential for being a different size?  What values do you want to use as filler if one list is longer than the other?

Comment: @loganjones16 sorry - yes my code checks to make sure the two lists are the same length. they are in a list object. would it help if the two lists were put into a numpy array?

Comment: I'd suggest casting things to numpy whenever you can just because it is easier to do complex functions with (check out numpy slicing, it's the best thing ever).  However, you have to know its length when you create it, no appending as you go.  This is because it can do performance optimizing if it has a set amount of space.  But you can always cast lists to ndarray using the numpy.asarray()

Comment: @loganjones16 thank you so much! you were extremely helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say in the comments, your x, y, and z values are repeated, you could create those pretty easy using `numpy.full`.  If the two lists of varying size are the same and determine the number of rows, it would be pretty easy to turn them into `numpy.ndarray`s by calling `list1 = numpy.asarray(list1)` and again for list2.  You can get their length using `len(list1)`.  You could then check out numpy stacking (hstack) functions for appending the numpy arrays together.

```
import numpy as np
# expects there to be scalars: x, y, and z 
# and two lists: list1, list2
length = len(list1)
list1 = np.asarray(list1)
list2 = np.asarray(list2)
x = np.full(length, x)
y = np.full(length, y)
z = np.full(length, z)

combo = np.hstack((x, y, z, list1, list2))
```

If this is all done in numpy, everything will need to be the same data type (int, float, boolean, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to know what your input lists are like but I'll make an attempt. 
 Something like this?

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = ['a','b','c','d']

output_array = [['x','y','z',a1,a2] for a1,a2 in zip(array1,array2)]
print(output_array)

[['x', 'y', 'z', 1, 'a'], 
 ['x', 'y', 'z', 2, 'b'], 
 ['x', 'y', 'z', 3, 'c'], 
 ['x', 'y', 'z', 4, 'd']]
```

Things I am using here:
[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) (iterates through 2 arrays and aligns them, first from one list with the first to the second list... then 2nds etc...)

[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions) (creates a list inline, google about it, lots of good explanations)

if you want to then turn that back into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d','e'], data=output_array)
```

Comment: Can you put this in numpy or pandas form? I think that's what the asker was looking for.

Comment: updated, based on the original question I think the starting data is in a list though.